# Como contar os elementos de um li em jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tem como contar os elemento que estão dentro da li, mas que seja por passo, por exemplo primeiro pegar a li1 e conta os elementos que no caso tem que voltar 3 e depois passe para outra li.

```
<ul>
   <li id='li1'>
     <a>elemento 1</a>
     <a>elemento 2</a>
     <a>elemento 3</a>
   </li>
   <li id='li2'>
     <a>elemento 1</a>
     <a>elemento 2</a>
     <a>elemento 3</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Um Array que contenha objetos {id: <id do tag li>, contador: <contador de elementos do li>} te atenderia?  Com ele você poderia implementar um iterador para compor seja lá qual for a computação que você queira. E isso? Realmente precisa de JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar o método `children`que retorna todos os filhos de um determinado elemento e obter o `length` dele.

```js
$('li').each(function() {
  var qtd = $(this).children().length;
  console.log(this.id, qtd);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li id='li1'>
     <a>elemento 1</a>
     <a>elemento 2</a>
     <a>elemento 3</a>
   </li>
   <li id='li2'>
     <a>elemento 1</a>
     <a>elemento 2</a>
     <a>elemento 3</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Resolve o problema, mas isso pode contar mais do que o necessário se existir outras coisas que não devem ser contadas dentro do li. Não seria melhor especificar qual elemento contar?

Answer (score 2):

Podes montar um array com o valor de quantos elementos cada `li` tem. Seria algo assim:

```js
var contador = $('ul li').get().reduce(function(obj, li) {
  obj[li.id] = li.children.length;
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(contador);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li id='li1'>
     <a>elemento 1</a>
     <a>elemento 2</a>
     <a>elemento 3</a>
   </li>
   <li id='li2'>
     <a>elemento 1</a>
     <a>elemento 2</a>
     <a>elemento 3</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Com JavaScript moderno nem era preciso jQuery e ficaria assim:

```js
var contador = [...document.querySelectorAll('ul li')].reduce(
  (obj, li) => (obj[li.id] = li.children.length, obj), {}
);

console.log(contador);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id='li1'>
    <a>elemento 1</a>
    <a>elemento 2</a>
    <a>elemento 3</a>
  </li>
  <li id='li2'>
    <a>elemento 1</a>
    <a>elemento 2</a>
    <a>elemento 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```